# Is there a difference between DataTable.Clear and DataTable.Rows.Clear?

Tags: .net

I recall there is a difference between some methods/properties called directly on the [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(VS.71).aspx) class, and the identically named methods/properties on the [DataTable.Rows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rows(VS.71).aspx) property. (Might have been the RowCount/Count property for which I read this.) The difference is one of them disregards [DataRow.RowState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rowstate(VS.71).aspx), and the other respects/uses it.

In this particular case I'm wondering about the difference between [DataTable.Clear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clear(VS.71).aspx) and [DataTable.Rows.Clear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.clear(VS.71).aspx). I can imagine one of them actually removes all rows, and the other one just marks them as deleted.

So my question is, **is there a difference between the two Clear methods, and if so what is the difference?**

(Oh, this is for .NET 1.1 btw, in case the semantics changed from one version to another.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In .Net 1.1, `DataRowCollection.Clear` calls `DataTable.Clear`

However, in .Net 2.0, there is a difference.
If I understand the source correctly, `DataTable.Clear` will clear unattached rows (created using `DataTable.NewRow`) whereas DataRowCollection.Clear won't.

The difference is in `RecordManager.Clear` (source below, from the [.Net Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx) for v3.5 SP 0); `clearAll` is true only when called from `DataTable.Clear`.

```
    internal void Clear(bool clearAll) { 
        if (clearAll) {
            for(int record = 0; record < recordCapacity; ++record) { 
                rows[record] = null;
            }
            int count = table.columnCollection.Count;
            for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) { 
                //

                DataColumn column = table.columnCollection[i]; 
                for(int record = 0; record < recordCapacity; ++record) {
                    column.FreeRecord(record); 
                }
            }
            lastFreeRecord = 0;
            freeRecordList.Clear(); 
        }
        else { // just clear attached rows 
            freeRecordList.Capacity = freeRecordList.Count + table.Rows.Count; 
            for(int record = 0; record < recordCapacity; ++record) {
                if (rows[record]!= null && rows[record].rowID != -1) { 
                    int tempRecord = record;
                    FreeRecord(ref tempRecord);
                }
            } 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

I've been testing the different methods now in .NET 1.1/VS2003, seems Matt Hamilton is right.

- DataTable.Clear and DataTable.Rows.Clear seem to behave identical with respect to the two things I tested: both remove all rows (they don't mark them as deleted, they really remove them from the table), and neither removes the columns of the table.
- DataTable.Reset clears rows and columns.
- DataTable.Rows.Count does include deleted rows. (This might be 1.1 specific)
- foreach iterates over deleted rows. (I'm pretty sure deleted rows are skipped in 2.0.)

Comment: Hooray!  Testing!  
(unlike my knee-jerk answer which I have since deleted)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, the main difference between `datatable.clear` and `datatable.rows.clear`, is that `datatable.clear` clears both rows and columns. So if you want to keep the table structure (i.e. columns), use `datatable.rows.clear`. And if you want to start from scratch, use `datatable.clear`, or even `datatable.reset` to go right back to the beginning.

`datatable.reset` is effectively the next level up from `datatable.clear`. Using `datatable.clear` will fail if there are any constraints applied that would be violated, but using `datatable.reset` will get rid of anything and everything that has been put in place since the datatable was created.

Comment: What would be difference between Clear and Reset?

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for, thanks. :) You are incorrect that `.Clear()` clears columns as well though; that is not true, however, `.Reset()` does. :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that DataTable.Clear does clear columns. This code writes "1" to standard output:

```
var d = new DataTable();
d.Columns.Add("Hello", typeof(string));
d.Clear();
Console.WriteLine(d.Columns.Count);
```

Comment: Unless it's a 1.1 thing. I don't have VS2003 to test it with.

Comment: No, I actually tested it now and this code writes "1" to standard output in .NET 1.1/VS2003 too.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between them. DataRowCollection.Clear() calls Table.Clear()

Table.Clear() checks that the table can be cleared (constraints can prevent this), removes the rows and rebuilds any indexes.

Answer (score -1):

Do Below and Its working absolutely fine....

```
DataRow[] d_row = dt_result.Select("isfor_report='True'");
DataTable dt = dt_result.Clone();                
foreach (DataRow dr in d_row)
{
     dt.ImportRow(dr);
}
gv_view_result.DataSource = dt;
gv_view_result.DataBind();
```

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score -2):

The both do the same thing. One is just an inherited method from the Collections class. And the Table.Clear() just calls that method.

Comment: Look at the System.Data assembly with Reflector and you'll see this is wrong.