# What is the difference between assigning a new DataTable, DataTable.Clear(), DataTable.Reset() and DataTable.Rows.Clear()?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using datatables to bind a `DataSource` to a `GridView`.
This is how I do it.

I declared the dattable as follows.

```
 private DataTable dt_CompanyNames;
```

Then

```
private void get_CompanyNames()
{
     dt_CompanyNames = new DataTable();
     dt_CompanyNames = objDesignation_Bll.Get_CompanyNames();
     gridCompanies.DataSource = dt_CompanyNames;
     gridCompanies.DataBind();
}
```

So my question is What If I do those in below ways.

First I have to do this.

```
private DataTable dt_CompanyNames=new DataTable();
```

Then in my method I am using these statements.

1) Method 1

```
 dt_CompanyNames.Clear();
```

2) Method 2

```
 dt_CompanyNames.Rows.Clear();
```

3) Method 3

```
 dt_CompanyNames.Reset();
```

4) Or should I stick with my exisiting method?

```
dt_CompanyNames = new DataTable();
```

In this method it always create new `Datatable` when each time this function calls. Is it good?

So what is the difference among those?  Is there one better than the other in terms of efficiency?

Comment: They are similar. I would use `new DataTable` since that has no side-effects (attached events etc.). Here's a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166159/is-there-a-difference-between-datatable-clear-and-datatable-rows-clear

Comment: It's not really a duplicate since the other questions just asks about the difference between `DataTable.Clear` and `DataRowCollection.Clear`.

Comment: @Belogix, Soner Gönül This is not a duplicate question. Dont flag this. Read whole question again.

Comment: @TimSchmelter _Well_, I don't like this kind of questions. It is %90 similar. Only difference is using `new DataTable();` makes difference or not. Re-opened anyway.. ;)

Comment: The question is still asking what is better though, and there is no real answer to that since they do different things. If he *wants* to keep the events (or allow other pieces of his code that is already referring to the same datatable) then he doesn't want the `new DataTable(...` method. So it depends.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: i assume that OP does not know the difference between these approaches, that's why he's asking this question. Ok, he could look at the documentation, but it's not that clear to inexperienced users.

Comment: I agree with that, but it's going to be hard to both answer this question for this user *and* leave something worthwhile for future visitors here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new DataTable()` assigns a new object to the variable referenced, by default all meta data weill be removed from DataTable.

`DataTable.Clear()` as per MSDN

> All rows in all tables are removed. An exception is generated if the
>   table has any enforced child relations that would cause child rows to
>   be orphaned.
>
> If the DataSet is bound to an XmlDataDocument, calling DataSet.Clear
>   or DataTable.Clear raises the NotSupportedException. To avoid this
>   situation, traverse each table, removing each row one at a time. When
>   you use NewRow to create new rows, the rows must be processed before
>   you call Clear.

From an Answer [HERE](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/be8066c7-0415-4977-9277-e73da98198b6/difference-between-datatableclear-and-datatablerowsclear)

> Both DataTable.Clear() and Rows.Clear() will just delete all rows from
>   datatable but not the columns. They both perform same function except
>   that One is defined in dataTable class and second one is defined in
>   DataRowCollection class.

Comment: So I assume that when I do dt_CompanyNames = new DataTable();. new object of datatable class
is created and the old datatable object will be collect by the Garbage collecter?
Am I right?

Comment: @user3769650 - yes, if it is no more in reference anywhere else!