# DataTable .clear doesn't remove the previous data

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net

I made an application that read data from database using a localhost connection.
 Now in the load event I establish the connection and insert all the available tables name into the `ComboBox1`, this control allow me to select the table where I want to read the data.
 How you can see I've created the `getData()` function, this function is necessary to take data from the selected table from the `ComboBox1`. 
Now the problem's that when I select for the second time another table I get the column of the previously table loaded and I don't know why 'cause I'm using `.Clear()` I've also tried with `.Reset()` and this seems working but if I use `.Reset()` I get empty table value.
 Another thing that's quite annoying is the use of more `DataTable`, infact if I use only `myName` also in the `getData()` function I get also the attribute `Table_Name`, so is possible also optimize the code?

**Code:**

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class DataIn

Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand
Dim myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
Dim myName As New DataTable
Dim myData As New DataTable
Dim SQL As String
Dim MysqlConn As MySqlConnection

Private Sub DataIn_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection()
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;" _
    & "user id=root;" _
    & "password=123456789;" _
    & "database=calendario"
    Try
        MysqlConn.Open()
        myCommand.Connection = MysqlConn
        myCommand.CommandText = SQL
        myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
        myAdapter.Fill(myName)
        For intcount = 0 To myName.Rows.Count - 1
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(myName.Rows(intcount).Item(0))
        Next
    Catch myerror As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(myerror.Message)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Close()
        MysqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    getData()
End Sub

Public Sub getData()
    Try
        SQL = "SELECT * FROM " & ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
        myCommand.CommandText = SQL
        myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
        myData.Clear() 
        myAdapter.Fill(myData)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing 
        DataGridView1.DataSource = myData
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Close()
        MysqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Try `dt.Rows.Clear()` and make sure that your select query is *not* retrieving same values in each time(_this might be a reason_)

Comment: on the datagrid or on myData?

Comment: On datatable .......... `myData.Rows.Clear()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using

`mydata.rows.clear()`

Hope it helps.you can know more [differences between datatable.clear() and datatable.rows.clear()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166159/is-there-a-difference-between-datatable-clear-and-datatable-rows-clear)

Comment: Instead of rows I put columns and working, thanks. Another question is possible use the same DataTable object instead of myName and myData?

Comment: ya no problem.just clear rows and columns before inserting new data.